# How to find GUI component by id for JUnit test in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, junit

I need to write a test for a class that (in my application) works with several TextView's. Normally the class gets the parent Activity and the view resource ids in constructor and then loads the TextViews and some other controls by calling `findViewById`. It is reused several times with different ids and parent activities.

It is an application test, the xml files describing the GUI are present and the view IDs are available as R.id.* . But how to load them now from the test case where I have no access to any `Activity`?

I tried the `AndroidTestCase`, it does provides access to `Context` but this seems not enough to load/access/resolve the GUI components by id. Then I tried `ApplicationTestCase` but it has very few methods and the `Application` instance that can be obtained through it also has no obvious way access GUI component by id.

**Question:**
When in JUnit test, can I obtain an instance of `TextView` using the same `R.id.myView` id as I use with `Activity.findViewById(R.id.myView)`? If I could, how?

**I tried:**

```
public void testIpSection() {
    Activity act = new Activity();
    act.setContentView(R.layout.testlayout); // NPE thrown
    FragmentManager fm = act.getFragmentManager();
    FSetup setup = (FSetup) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.test_setup); 
    IPSection secs = new IPSection(setup, R.id.sbA0, R.id.sbA1, R.id.sbA2);
}
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/test_setup"
    android:name="com.spectraseis.fo4.qcdownload.FSetup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</fragment>
```

but I get NPE at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867) thrown from the second line in the test. Probably Activity cannot be instantiated just like that. How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you cant create activity this way. There are special classes to test activities. Read [this doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html) and choose between ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2/ActivityUnitTestCase/SingleLaunchActivityTestCase.